# pouchdb/couchdb authentication: create private databases for the users who sign up

Tags: javascript, couchdb, pouchdb

I'm using PouchDB with [PouchDB-authentication](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-authentication) plug-in to sign up users. I'm able to sign up users with the following code:

```
username='potato' 
password='potato chips crisis'
const dummyDB=new window.PouchDB('http://192.168.145.19:5984/dummy',
    {skipSetup:true})
dummyDB.signup(username, password).then(res=>{
        //user is signed up
        //now, how to create a database for the user who just signed up?
    }).catch(err=>{
        window.console.log('Error: ', err)
    })
```

The above code signs the user up without any problem, but it doesn't create any database associated with the user and the dummy database [is just a dummy one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30030008/7312233).

Now I wonder how I can create databases associated to the user I just signed up so that only that use can read/write to them.

---

UPDATE:

Looks like the way to go is like this:

```
const username='potato'
const password='potato chips crisis'

let realDBRemote
let realDBLocal

const dummyDB=new window.PouchDB('http://192.168.145.19:5984/dummy',
    {skipSetup:true})

dummyDB.signup(username, password).then(res=>{
        /**
         * user is signed up,
         * so now, we might create real databases (rather than dummy onee):
         */
        realDBRemote=new window.PouchDB('http://192.168.145.19:5984/'+
            username,{skipSetup:false})
        realDBLocal=new window.PouchDB(username)
        /**
         * and now you're able to do stuff to real databases like login:
         */
        return realDBRemote.login(username, password /*,ajaxOpts*/)
    }).then(res=>{
        /**
         * We might be able to sync remote/local real databases too:
         */
        realDBLocal.sync(realDBRemote,{live:true,retry:true})
            .on('error',err=>{console.log('Error:', err)})
    }).catch(err=>{
        window.console.log('Error: ', err)
    })
```

I'm not sure of the above method is the best practice, however my app looks fine with it.

Comment: I think you mean `skip_setup` instead of `skipSetup` (maybe the latter works, but I don't see it documented anywhere).

Comment: @Flimzy Thanks. Nice observation, I didn't notice that. [Here](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-authentication) when searching for `skip`, I realized that he is using both `{skipSetup: true}` and `{skip_setup: true}`

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if that's an oversight.  I'll raise an issue to find out :)  (Edit: issue filed [here](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-authentication/issues/147))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a database, just call `new PouchDB` *without* the `skip_setup` option provided. This is documented in the [PouchDB API docs](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#create_database).

```
var db = new PouchDB('http://192.168.145.19:5984/realDatabaseName');
```